# Change content (Text) in Wordpress TopBar Plugin @media screen

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, media-queries

I am wanting to change the actual content inside the Wordpress TopBar Plugin for certain screen sizes such as iPad, tablet & mobile.
Not too sure why this will not work, can anyone advise?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #tpbr_box {
        content: "Register for 10% Discount";
    }

    #tpbr_calltoaction {
        content: "Yes Please!";
    }
}
```

**tpbr_bx** = The top bar with text that needs changing

**tpbr_calltoaction** = button with text that needs changing

Comment: Are there any filters available to do this?  The Gettext filter might work on these titles.

Comment: By filters, do you mean shortcodes within the plugin? If so then no.
you can view the website here www.thailandpoolshop.com

Comment: Erm no, WordPress filters, one of the core elements of the platform.  Viewing the website won't tell me anything I need to see the source code of the plugin.  What's the URL to download the plugin?

Comment: I took a look at the source code for that plugin and you can't manipulate the message text without hacking the core code.  You can always fork the code and create your own version of the plugin ;)

Comment: Here's an idea that you could manipulate to do what you want. https://blog.escapecreative.com/how-to-replace-text-with-css/  You could use some jQuery/javascript to delete the current content and set it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Andrew!
It has change to the correct text using:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
#tpbr_box,
#tpbr_calltoaction {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#tpbr_box:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: "Register for 10% Discount" !important;
}

#tpbr_calltoaction:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: "Yes Please!" !important;
}
}
```

The only problem now is that it hasn't carried over the old CSS formatting that the original had. Such as:

```
#tpbr_calltoaction {
    background: #76b51b !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
}

#tpbr_calltoaction:hover {
    background: #01ace4 !important;
}
```

I could easily add these into the **:after** sections I suppose.

And then final problem now is that the button **tpbr_calltoaction** is appearing above the text **tpbr_box**. Why would it do this? Surely the normal thing to do would be to do them in the order they are in the code, Haha.